# subset one dataframe by using column names and group by row names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, automation

I am currently having a DataFrame (df1) and currently try to split df1 into 3 small DataFrames and named by original df1 column's name (col_1df,col_2df,col_3df),and the first column in df1 should become the column name of new dfs shown as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COmLp.png)

Comment: try `pivot`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: please provide your input dataframe & the expected dataframe, that is much easier to understand & work with. You can directly paste the contents from excel into the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Pivot Table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) as follows:

Sample data (CSV):

```
a,date,v1,v2 
a1,2019-01-01,1,2
a1,2019-01-02,1,3
a2,2019-01-01,2,3
a3,2019-01-01,1,3
```

Load this CSV in pandas dataframe, using `pandas.read_csv()` function.
Then just apply pivot_table as follows:

```
df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='a', values='v1')
a            a1   a2   a3
date                     
2019-01-01  1.0  2.0  1.0
2019-01-02  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Accordingly, you can do for other columns.

Note: Always post sample data in easily accessible way, image is not best practice.

**Edit:**

If you want automated way of doing it for all target columns, then best I can think of it is creating dictionary, in which keys are your names of dataframe and values are corresponding dataframe itself.

Here it is:

```
d=dict()
target_cols=list(set(df.columns)-{'date','a'})
for col in target_cols:
    d[col+"_df"]=df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='a', values=col)
```

Accessing one of keys:

```
print(d['v1_df'])
a            a1   a2   a3
date                     
2019-01-01  1.0  2.0  1.0
2019-01-02  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: also wondering if there is a looping way that can save some effort to create those data frames in a name

Comment: also wondering if there is a looping way that can save some effort to create those data frames in one row, with there names such as a_df,b_df,c_df

Comment: @Andy Updated answer.

Comment: @Andy Great! Glad to help. If it solves your problem, consider accepting answer.